# recursive Permutation of a 3 Digit Number

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I am working on finding All permutations of a 3-Digit Number recursively.

I am tired with making up the following permutation Method:

```
    static int a = 1;
    static int b = 2;
    static int c = 3;
    static int aCount;
    static int bCount;
    static int cCount;

    static void perm(int a, int b, int c)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("( {0}, {1}, {2} )", a, b, c); // (1,2,3 )

        if (aCount < 1 && bCount<1 &&cCount<1)
        {
            aCount++;

            perm(a, c, b);
        }
        else
            if (aCount==1 && bCount < 1 && cCount<1)
            {

                bCount++;
                perm(b, a, c);
            }
            else
                if (aCount == 1 && bCount == 1 && cCount < 1)
                 {
                    perm(b,c,a);
                  }
        else
                if (aCount==1 && bCount==1 && cCount < 1)
                {
                    cCount++;
                    perm(c, a, b);  //c b a

                }
               else
                    if (aCount == 1 && bCount == 1 &&  cCount == 1)
                {
                    perm(c, b, a);

                }

            }
```

I tried to Cover ALL cases, with the specifics at each step, and still I get a Stack overflow Exception out of the Blue.

I Appreciate Your Contributions, so Thanks Forwards.

Comment: Please initialize aCount, bCount and cCount to 0 before you start.

Comment: oh, sorry, I must have missed that, while I was experimenting :P

Answer (score 3):

You're saying you're trying recursion, but all those lines appear in your code:

```
perm(a, c, b)
perm(b, a, c)
perm(b, c, a)
perm(c, a, b)
perm(c, b, a)
```

and of course the first call of the function: `perm(a, b, c)`

It's much easier to do:

```
static void perm(int a, int b, int c)
{
    Console.WriteLine("( {0}, {1}, {2} )", a, b, c);
    Console.WriteLine("( {0}, {2}, {1} )", a, b, c);
    Console.WriteLine("( {1}, {0}, {2} )", a, b, c);
    Console.WriteLine("( {1}, {2}, {0} )", a, b, c);
    Console.WriteLine("( {2}, {0}, {1} )", a, b, c);
    Console.WriteLine("( {2}, {1}, {0} )", a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: I wish it was like that! I am asked to write a RECURSIVE permutation function,Only :S

Comment: I need a Recursive way that prints line for each Permutation.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, either of these two cases will lead to infinite recursion:

```
if (aCount == 1 && bCount == 1 && cCount < 1)
{
    perm(b,c,a);
}
```

And:

```
if (aCount == 1 && bCount == 1 && cCount == 1)
{
    perm(c, b, a);
}
```

The reason for this is that you don't change `aCount`, `bCount` or `cCount`, so you'll end up triggering the same case repeatedly.

Beyond that, you don't really seem to thinking of the problem recursively - as mentioned in the other answer, all the permutations appear in a single call, so, if you get it to work that way, your recursion depth will 2, which could then essentially involve replacing every recursive call with a print statement, and having a non-recursive function.

For a recursive solution, try to think of a solution where you handle a single character in the current call, and recurse onto the next.

A more detailed explanation, if you can't figure it out:

> Start at the first character.
>
> Try to swap the current character with each remaining character (including itself, i.e. do nothing).
>
> Recurse onto the next character.
>
> At the last character, print out all characters.
>
> Hint - pass an array and current index to your function.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write you the pseudo code:

```
permutationABC()
{
    int n=3;
    array SOL[n]/* 1 if you get the element  otherwise 0 if you don't get the element , the meaning of SOL is that SOL[0] is 1 if we had got 'a' , otherwise 0. It's the same for the others */
    initSolWithAllZero(SOL)
    permRecursive(abc,SOL,0,n);
}

permRecursive(SOL,i,n)
{
    if i == n then print(SOL) 
    else
    {
        for k=0 to n
        {
             if SOL[k] == 0 then
             {
                  SOL[k]=1 // take 
                  permRecursive(SOL,i+1,n)
                  SOL[K]=0 // don't take ... go back....
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The time is O(n*n!) O(n!) is the number of permutation and O(n) is the time that is the printing time.